# Wicket: redirect to shared resource

Tags: redirect, resources, wicket

i've got a wicket form, which when submitted should give users a file to download. the file is generated by an external servlet (based on the form), which writes generated content to response's output stream.

normally this can be done using `getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new RedirectRequestTarget(redirectUrl);` on form submit, where `redirectUrl` will be the external servlet's url with parameters.

however, `redirectUrl` shows up in browser's address bar, which is not good as users see parameter values, which they shouldn't.

in order to overcome that, i've implemented a custom `DynamicWebResource`, which fetches the servlet output as `byte[]` and is bound to a virtual url through usual wicket shared resource mechanism.

on form submit i do the following:

```
RequestParameters rps = new RequestParameters();
rps.setResourceKey(new ResourceReference("myResource").getSharedResourceKey());
getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new SharedResourceRequestTarget(rps));
```

and then rely on wicket's internal ways of handling.

when debugging i can clearly see that my shared resource is correctly invoked, the external servlet's response is correctly generated, fetched and then written to current response with all the headers and stuff, but nothing happens after that, no errors, just nothing.

when i call my shared resource directly specifying the url wicket has bound it to (like `http://localhost:8080/webAppRoot/wicket/myResource?param1=value`) - everything works, file is well-formed and downloadable.

is there something additional i have to do? it's most probably something stupid, but i've been banging my head agains the wall for a day already...

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of the onSubmit() handler?

Comment: it's there already, there's nothing else. all the actual business is done in my shared resource.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. the reason for the response not to be processed by the browser was the fact that the form was submitted using AJAX. changing submit type to plain solved the issue.